# Server Architecture of Real-Time Updates App

Tags: wcf, architecture, websocket, real-time, updates

I'm building a stock ticker that requires continuous real-time updates.  JavaScript on the client talking to .NET WCF 4.5, which introduced support for WebSockets.

Users' feeds vary significantly.  For example, many users follow popular big-caps like FB, GOOG and MSFT, but each user follows many other "niche" stocks that may be unique to him.

We all know there are a few options for refreshing the browser in real-time.

1. Polling.  Pros:  Easy implementation.  Cons:  Doesn't scale, primitive, wastes bandwidth and cycles.
2. Long-polling.  Pros:  Efficient, scalable.  Cons:  Antiquated?
3. WebSockets.  Pros.  Efficient, scalable.  Cons:  None I can think of as most modern browsers support them as per [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/websockets).

Would anyone pick anything other than 3.?

Assuming I go with 3., how are the server's open connections kept track of?  For example, if we design such that we keep a pool of FB "followers" (i.e., client connections interested in FB's price changes) so that we know whom to update when a price change occurs, how is this pool maintained?  By a service that runs constantly in memory?  Also, if a FB follower closes her browser, does the service need to catch this event and update FB's follower pool?  This is where I get fuzzy quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this post about the hard sides of long polling : [Hard downsides of long polling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676324/hard-downsides-of-long-polling)

> how are the server's open connections kept track of?

Probably there is a way in WCF WebSockets to have connect and disconnect events. If not, you definitely should keep an eye in other frameworks. I took a look to WCF websockets some time ago, and it didn't look like something I would like to use, put aside you need Windows 8 or Windows 2012 to use it.

You should consider websockets like just and endpoint. You should develop your stock ticker software with a event driven architecture approach, and then provide endpoints for receiving/delivering events, that would be a totally different part of the app. For event management I recommend you to take a look to [MassTransit project](http://masstransit-project.com/).

When you have that clear then you can define how user will connect to your service and interact with it. In a web event driven architecture, websockets make a lot of sense because it is a full duplex, persistent connection and also a broadly supported web standard.

In order to provide websockets to .NET, WCF is not the only option, and it may not be the best neither. In order to add a websocket endpoint to your architecture, I recommend you to take a look at [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/), that is a very small component for providing websocket capability (disclaimer: I developed it), or [XSocket.NET](http://xsockets.net/) if you want a more complex solution that does many things.  Take a look to this example done with XSocket.NET : https://github.com/codeplanner/Simple.StockTicker